# Setting same value using set function in Record is creating a new object

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I am using Immutable Record in ReduceStore to avoid emmitting the change in case of there there is no data change. Even for the same data, Immutable.js creating new object and ReduceStore areEqual function return false and emit the changes. 
I am using following structure

```
const Rec = Immutable.Record({
   status: Immutable.List()
});
```

and setting an same element in status

```
const rec2 = rec.set('status', Immutable.List(status));
```

in above snippet, staus is recieved from the action and it is similar to existing status value in the state.

Below is the codepen which shows the issue I am facing :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrvKaw?editors=1111

Please help me if it is possible or my understanding of getting the same object for the same values is wrong.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`is`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is) method to perform equality checks, because the code is creating two different mutations of the same object.

Here's the code (modified your codepen) -

```
var b= ['one'];

const Rec = Immutable.Record({
   status: Immutable.List()
});
const rec = new Rec();
// value equality
const rec2 = rec.set('status', Immutable.fromJS(b));
const rec3 = rec.set('status', Immutable.fromJS(b));
console.log(Immutable.is(rec2, rec3)); // true
// or
console.log(rec2.is(rec3)); // true

// reference equality
const rec4 = rec.set('status', Immutable.fromJS(b));
const rec5 = rec4.setIn(['status', 0], 'one');
console.log(rec4 === rec5); //true
```

Here, both `rec2` and `rec3` are different mutations stemming from `rec`. Although they are *value equal*, they are not *referentially equal*. The `is` method compares deep value equality and returns true.

In the next example, `rec4` mutates from `rec`, while `rec5` uses `ref4` to only update the `status` List item at `0` with new value. In this case, `Record` ensures that the returned state is the same because the values match and don't result in a new mutation.